# jQuery toggle class on label onclick of radio

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to toggle 'active' class on 2 labels when you click on radio/label. So on page load the first radio is checked and label for that radio has class 'active' then if you clicked on the other radio/label it would toggle the active class. I've almost got it working i'm just doing something slightly wrong.

```js
$('.label_item input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent('.label_item').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.label_item').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="label_item active" for="a1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" checked="checked" />label one</label>

<label class="label_item" for="a2">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" />label two</label>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vnhgduh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add class to parent and remove class from parent's siblings.

```js
$('.label_item input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings('label').removeClass('active')
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label_item active" for="a1">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" checked="checked" />label one</label>

<label class="label_item" for="a2">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" />label two</label>
```

Comment: Also you can use `:radio` instead of `input[type="radio"]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `active` class on `:checked` radio button and I would recommed you to use `change` event.

```
var elements = $('.label_item :radio').change(function() {
    elements  //Select radio
      .parent().removeClass('active') //target parents and remove class
      .end() //target radio options 
      .filter(':checked') //get checked radio
      .parent().addClass('active'); //add class
});
```

```js
var elements = $('.label_item :radio').change(function() {
  elements //Select radio
    .parent().removeClass('active') //target parents and remove class
    .end() //target radio options 
    .filter(':checked') //get checked radio
    .parent().addClass('active'); //add class
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label_item active" for="a1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" checked="checked" />label one</label>

<label class="label_item" for="a2">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" />label two</label>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/3ymb20eu/)